# Cannot retreive virtual card number in test mode via stripe API using Go examples

Tags: go, stripe-payments

Trying to follow the example here: https://stripe.com/docs/issuing/cards/virtual
When I add  `params.AddExpand("number")`, no number is returned, yet via the dashboard I was able to see the card numbers. Here's sample code and redacted info for the Req and Resp.

```golang
func (ac *appContext) CardRetrieve(id string) *stripe.IssuingCard {
    stripe.Key = ac.Config.Stripe.SecretKey

    params := stripe.IssuingCardParams{}

    params.AddExpand("number")
    params.AddExpand("cvc")

    ic_num, _ := card.Get(id, &params)

    return ic_num
}
```

Returns:

```json
{
  "id": "ic_redacted",
  "object": "issuing.card",
  "brand": "Visa",
  "cancellation_reason": null,
  "cardholder": {
    "id": "ich_redacted",
    "object": "issuing.cardholder",
    "billing": {
      "address": {
        "city": "A Beach",
        "country": "US",
        "line1": "404 Main St.",
        "line2": "Suite #302",
        "postal_code": "19001",
        "state": "DE"
      }
    },
    "company": null,
    "created": 1613338532,
    "email": "redacted@notreal.com",
    "individual": {
      "dob": {
        "day": 20,
        "month": 10,
        "year": 1990
      },
      "first_name": "User",
      "last_name": "Testing",
      "verification": {
        "document": {
          "back": null,
          "front": null
        }
      }
    },
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": {
    },
    "name": "User Testing",
    "phone_number": "+15165551212",
    "requirements": {
      "disabled_reason": "under_review",
      "past_due": [
      ]
    },
    "spending_controls": {
      "allowed_categories": [
      ],
      "blocked_categories": [
      ],
      "spending_limits": [
        {
          "amount": 1,
          "categories": [
          ],
          "interval": "daily"
        }
      ],
      "spending_limits_currency": "usd"
    },
    "status": "active",
    "type": "individual"
  },
  "created": 1613338532,
  "currency": "usd",
  "exp_month": 1,
  "exp_year": 2024,
  "last4": "0088",
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "replaced_by": null,
  "replacement_for": null,
  "replacement_reason": null,
  "shipping": null,
  "spending_controls": {
    "allowed_categories": null,
    "blocked_categories": null,
    "spending_limits": [
      {
        "amount": 1,
        "categories": [
        ],
        "interval": "daily"
      }
    ],
    "spending_limits_currency": "usd"
  },
  "status": "inactive",
  "type": "virtual"
}
```

What confuses me is the documentation found here:
https://stripe.com/docs/issuing/cards/virtual

It says: You can retrieve both the full unredacted card number and CVC from the API. For security reasons, these fields are only available for virtual cards and will be omitted unless you explicitly request them with the expand property. Additionally, they are only available through the [Retrieve a card](https://stripe.com/docs/api/issuing/cards/retrieve) endpoint. That links to the issue card retrieval end point, but the params defined in the virtual cards example references the `CardParams{}` struct.

No of the examples show what imported module their aliasing for card to exec card.Get, but it stands to reason given the flow of the documentation that this should be `IssuingCardParams{}` and that the card alias is referencing: `"github.com/stripe/stripe-go/issuing/card"`

I also find it strange that we're defining params in the example but not passing it into the `card.Get()`

---

Edit:

I went digging through the module and it seems like to get the card details you have to call:  `details, _ := card.Details(id, params)` but I get a 404 when trying to call that. The object returned is actually the right object and I see `number` and `cvc`, albeit `nil`.

I get the following error:

```
2021/02/15 00:33:06 Request error from Stripe (status 404): {"status":404,"message":"Unrecognized request URL (GET: /v1/issuing/cards/ic_redacted/details). Please see https://stripe.com/docs
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you need to include a /v72 in the import:

`"github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v72"`

The documentation should be updated to show this and the virtual card example for go should also be updated.

Comment: This inclusion of a major version in imports is a convention of the Go language for all module imports, not something decided by Stripe related to the `stripe-go` client.
https://golang.org/ref/mod#major-version-suffixes